# Share common section between multiple cabal files

Tags: haskell, cabal

I am setting up a project with a `cabal.project` in the root and many cabal files in their own directories. I would like to share a `common` stanza which can be imported from all of the `*.cabal` files in the repository. (This is helpful for a standard set of language extensions).

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think such a thing exists. This may be a valid feature request. OTOH .cabal files are meant to be self-contained, so I'm not sure that would be a logical feature to add.